# Rollback complete database one hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We had some problems this morning and need to rollback our database for about one hour. Is this possible and how is it done?

It is a Microsoft SQL 2005 database.

Comment: In the future I sugest looking into backup solutions BEFORE the accident occurs. I sure hope this database is an unimportant one or someone should be in trouble...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find the previous full backup of your database (BF1).
2. Take a backup of the log file (BL1).
3. Take a full backup of the database (BF2). Good to have, in case the following steps go wrong.
4. Restore the previous full backup (BF1), with NORECOVERY
5. Restore the log file backup (BL1) with RECOVERY, and specifying the point in time you want to recover.

Comment: Is this possible when the recoverymodel is set to simple?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Your database.
2. Then select Tasks/Restore/Database.
3. On the restore database dialog select the Timeline option
4. Enter the time from when you want to revert your database.
5. Click ok
6. Ok Again.
7. Your database updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have done some investigating and it seems that since our database has RECOVERYMODEL set to  SIMPLE it is not possible to do a rollback.

If the database was set up with full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model it would have been easier.

Comment: I suppose the "good news", if any, is that you'll know what to do if it happens again...